# How to change the formatting/font of page numbers?

Tags: fonts, formatting, page-numbering, header-footer

So, I'm using the article class, and I'd like to make the page number smaller, and set it in a different font. I don't need to create a new pagestyle, necessarily, and I'm hesitant to do so without understanding the ramifications.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion to use fancyhdr/redefine page styles. From the fancyhdr manual:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the example code, this is very useful!

Answer (score 10):

You could use a KOMA-script class (e.g. `scrartcl` instead of `article`) and add the following to the preamble:

```
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small\sffamily}
```

I initially recommended to redefine the  `\thepage` command but, as Lev Bishop has pointed out, this has adverse effects and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Sorry lockstep, I didn't notice you'd posted your solution as I was posting mine.  Here's +1 by way of apology `;)`

Comment: Changing `\thepage` this way is  a **really bad idea**. It will make `see page \pageref{lbl} for more information` Expand to `see page \small\sffamily3 for more information` (setting "for more information" small and sans serif") which is surely not desired, and it will cause `hyperref` to fail completely.

Comment: @Lev Bishop: You're of course right. Not sure what I was thinking. :-( @Marcin: Disregard the first part of my answer. You should either use a KOMA-script class or wait for someone who doesn't give blindfold pieces of advice.

Comment: But the KOMA-script info should still be correct. Could you edit your answer so that it mainly shows that.

Comment: @lockstep, hope you don't mind that I've edited your answer to remove the incorrect information and only leave the valid suggestion of using KOMA-script. Please feel free to revert these changes, or edit the question yourself if you feel this doesn't represent the original intention of your answer.

Comment: I like your version of my answer better. ;-) Give a correct solution and only then mention your initial blunder.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to achieve this **is** to make a new page style. As [this FAQ answer](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-the-commands) discusses, redefining the `\thepage` will only cause problems with all the places page numbers are used (`\pageref`, table of contents, hyperref labels, etc, etc). Such changes will also not survive past a book-class change from `\frontmatter` to `\mainmatter` and so on.

Changing the pagestyle is easy enough with [the fancyhdr package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: As Lev kindly pointed out in his comment about it breaking various things, you definitely shouldn't think of this:

---

I can't help you with your font unless you mention which font you'd like.  However, this code should give you a start:

```
\let\oldthepage\thepage
\renewcommand*\thepage{\small{\ttfamily-- \oldthepage\ --}}
```

Comment: Changing `\thepage` this way is  a **really bad idea**. It will make `see page \pageref{lbl}.` Expand to `see page {\small{\ttfamily-- 3\ --}}.` which is surely not desired, and it will cause `hyperref` to fail completely.

Comment: Lev's right of course. Now he points it out, it's quite obviously a really bad idea.