# Is it possible to prevent some part of text (headers, footers) from selection?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, accsupp

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to prevent some parts of the final pdf file (header, footer) from being selected and copied. It is to allow easier quoting of longer parts of texts from documents that will be published.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/is-it-possible-to-provide-alternative-text-to-use-when-copying-text-from-the-pdf

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47486/9092), you could use [`accsupp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) to define a `\squelch` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\DeclareRobustCommand\squelch[1]{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}
This text is selectable \squelch{but this text isn't}.
\end{document}
```

The squelched text cannot be highlighted in Acrobat, and copying the whole line gives this:

> This text is selectable .

It's easy to combine this with `fancyhdr`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{\squelch{\thepage}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

You could also define a variant `\squelchstyle` for use with KOMA-Script's `\addtokomafont`:

```
\def\squelchstyle{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}%
    \aftergroup\aftersquelchstyle}
\def\aftersquelchstyle{\EndAccSupp{}}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\squelchstyle}
```

Comment: This works even when viewing the document in evince. Amazing!

Comment: Redefining `\thepage` to do anything other than return a page number is a really bad idea. See the answers to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3731/627 and squelch the page numbers by defining a new page style (eg with the `fancyhdr` package).

Comment: etextools seems to cause problems with biblatex, is there another way to use something like squelchstyle?

Comment: nice, that does the job I was looking for

Comment: Is there any way to get this working with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` (GhostScript)?

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann From the `accsupp` manual: "Package option `dvips` and its alias `dvipsone` write pdfmark specials in the output. Unhappily these pdfmark operators are ignored by `ghostscript` (latest tested version is 8.54). Perhaps they are recognized by commercial distiller applications." I can confirm that `accsupp` is compatible with Acrobat Distiller 10.1.