# What exactly does \pagenumbering do?

Tags: page-numbering, copy-paste

I am trying to squelch the page numbers using the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49505/is-it-possible-to-prevent-some-part-of-text-headers-footers-from-selection). This works fine, if one uses ordinary page numbers. If the page numbers are modified with the pagenumbering command, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{accsupp}
% Defining the squelch command
\DeclareRobustCommand\squelch[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}
% Trying to squelch the page numbers
\let\oldthepage\thepage
\def\thepage{\squelch{\oldthepage}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Next Chapter}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pagenumbering` redefines `\thepage`.

Comment: okay, so implementing \let\oldthepage\thepage \def\thepage{\squelch{\oldthepage}} after each pagenumbering command seems to do the job.

Comment: I've updated my original answer to work with `\pagenumbering`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to load `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrplain}

% Defining the squelch command
\DeclareRobustCommand\squelch[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

% Trying to squelch the page numbers
\ofoot[\normalfont\squelch{\thepage}]{\normalfont\squelch{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Next Chapter}
\end{document}
```