# Protect footnotemarks from selection in pdf

Tags: pdf, footnotes, copy-paste, accsupp

Inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49505/is-it-possible-to-prevent-some-part-of-text-headers-footers-from-selection) i used [`accsupp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) to protect the headers of my pdf from being copied which works nicely so far. 
I tried to do the same thing for the footnotemarks which hasn't worked so far. Screenshot:

[image]

I tried using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\arabic{footnote}\EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{This is a footnote}
\end{document}
```

An ideas? The actual text of the footnote should stay selectable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is fragility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{%
  \protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\arabic{footnote}\protect\EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a test\footnote{This is a footnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]