# Copy verse out of pdf mantaining margin structure

Tags: margins, copy-paste, verse, poetry

I use LaTeX to nicely typeset poems with the package `verse`.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}
\verselinenumbersleft
\poemlines{2}
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{Garden}

\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed. \\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Yet when I copy/paste the poem from the PDF into a plain text file (such as MS Word) I loose the margin formatting:

```
Garden
I used to love my garden
2 But now my love is dead
For I found a bachelor's button
4 In black-eyed Susan's bed.
```

Is there anyway to structure the PDF so to embed the information of the margins (maybe with a tab character) into the text strings? Or should I use a `tabular` environment instead of a `verse` environment? Of course, the latter will be preferred.

Comment: Sincerely I can't see what's the problem?. Why you have to copy the poem from the PDF and paste it into Word o_O? Could you explain it better?

Comment: If you want to squelch line numbers and preserve any indentation, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49507 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148661/7883.