Hide text from displaying using nonprintable unicode characters visible to ChatGPT
I don't know if this is possible so this question might be quickly closed. Related to the questions here, here, and here.
When text is hidden but selectable and searchable, once it is copy pasted the hidden text is revealed. Take for example the website https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php which has a string that can be copied "See what's hidden in your string…    or be​hind﻿" that contains the unicode characters U+A0, U+200B, and U+FEFF. Those extra characters are not revealed once copy pasted. Can I achieve something similar in LaTeX so that a sentence "A blue triangle" shows as "A triangle" even when copy pasted but somehow has unicode characters that represent the letters b, l, u, and e?
End goal? I'd like to insert hidden text in the form of unicode characters that chatGPT can recognise but a user cannot. This will allow me to hide instructions into questions that students are copying into chatgpt.

Interesting. Do you use XeLaTeX, or how do you handle Unicode with Latex?

@MS-SPO depends. Some unicode characters won't display on a PDF when using XeLaTeX or Lua and some won't display on PDFLaTeX but will on XeLaTeX or Lua. XeTeX is basically being phased out in favour of Lua. utf8x , unixode, ucs are all packages that support some form of unicode. The problem is achieving an output that displays normal but is interpretable by GPT.

I haven't tried it but I think ChatGPT can also take a screenshot of a question as input, for which your idea wouldn't work.

You can simply make some words non selectable, while they are still printed in pdf. Check this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49507/213149

@antshar this idea works too thank you.

I am going to go ahead and answer this question using a simple solution that has been mentioned elsewhere using accsupp.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}

Here is something to paste into ChatGPT. If is is long enough
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText=users and students}%
  {users }%
 \EndAccSupp{}%
probably won't notice that something small was added.

\end{document}

Output:

While it doesn't do what I initially wanted in terms of other hidden Unicode characters, it does have the advantage of slipping in extra information that could go unnoticed. This was compiled in PdfLaTeX.
